# NAND over NOR in Haskell

Tags: haskell, boolean-logic

Haskell beginner here. I want to show that NAND distributes over NOR in haskell. This should give me back "True", but I keep getting false. I'm not even sure if I'm approaching it correctly, but this is what I've tried:

```
nand_distributes_nor :: Bool
nand_distributes_nor = and [(a `nand` (b `nor` c)) == ((a `nand` b) `nor` (a `nand` c)) | a<-bools, b<-bools, c<-bools]
```

Comment: Are you sure NAND distributes over NOR? It doesn't look like it does to me: ``let (a, b, c) = (True, True, False) in a `nand` (b `nor` c)`` gives `True` while ``let (a, b, c) = (True, True, False) in (a `nand` b) `nor` (a `nand` c)`` gives `False`.

Answer (score 4):

Trying to prove the impossible, it's almost always not true (except all a=b=c=True)